# WCF service parameters from Flash are empty

Tags: flash, wcf-binding

I have a Flash app that needs to save some data in a Database using a WCF web service. The WCF service is configured to use basicHttpBinding.

The flash app is being developed by some other guy in a different environment, and there is no connection between flash and the wcf service. So I created the wcf service, saved the corresponding wsdl to a file and used it to create the flash references and parameter mappings.

The problem is, when we deploy the flash app to test the connection with the service, it does connect, but all the parameters are empty. We are tracing the service POST request using Firebug extension for Firefox, and it's something like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <GetContactInfo xmlns="http://www.company.com/simulator">
   <idNumber />
  </GetContactInfo>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

despite of the parameter idNumber being mapped to some field in the flash app and this field having some non-empty value.

The person responsible for the flash app told me that when he tests the flash app in his environment, connecting to a non-existent wcf endpoint, the parameters are fine (but he receives a 404 not found, obviously).

I really have no clue if this is related exclusively to the service parameter mappings in flash, or the wcf endpoint configuration. Has anyone experienced this issue before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the problem, but maybe you need a crossdomain.xml file on the server?

Comment: I have the crossdomain.xml on the server... Actually, I've tried the two scenarios: having the service on the same domain than the flash app (where the crossdomaim.xml file isn't required), and having it on a different one. The result is the same for both cases.

Comment: Have you tried your service with WcfTestClient.exe? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, the service works fine with WcfTestClient and with a WinForms tester.